# How do you square a vector in VBA without looping

Tags: vba

I have a vector. How do I square it without looping in vba?

```
s(0) = 4
s(1) = 5
```

sq = ??

i am looking for:

```
sq(0)= 16
sq(1) = 25
```

any thoughts?

Comment: You can't.  Write a loop, and get on with life.

Comment: There is no other operation on array than join (and split or Array itself) so the loop is needed

Comment: You could write a function that calls a more matrix friendly language like R or python and do your squaring, joining, splitting and other matrix operations there.  @RobertHarvey has the best answer though...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping *each time*, you can encapsulate this operation in a function and simply call that:

```
'Modifies array in place - saves from having to determine array type
Public Sub ArrayPower(arr As Variant, power As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
       arr(i) = arr(i) ^ power
    Next
End Function
```

In your code you can call it like so:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim arr(2) As Long
    arr(0) = 1
    arr(1) = 2
    arr(2) = 3

    'Before: {1,2,3}        

    ArrayPower arr, 2

    'After: {1,4,9}
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In Excel VBA, you can use

```
sq = Application.Power(s, 2)
```